# Displaying contents in HTML

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm currently doing a RoR project where I need to display certain things side-by-side. But I'm unable to do it. Could you guys help me out with it.

This is the code from which I'm reading my data from a database.

```
<h1>Results for your search.</h1>

<%=r ender "shirts/new"%>
    </br>
    </br>
    <div class="container">
        <% for prod in @results %>
            <div class="image">
                <%=i mage_tag(prod.image, :alt=>"logo", :size => "75x75") %>
            </div>
            <div class="name">
                <h3> <%= prod.name %> </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="price">
                <h5>New Price:</h5>
                <%=( prod.maxprice)-(prod.maxprice * prod.discount / 100)%>
            </div>
            <div class="price">
                 <h5>Old Price:</h5>
                <%=p rod.maxprice%>
            </div>
            <% end %>
    </div>
```

And here is the CSS file for the styling:

```
   .container {
       width: 200px;
       float: left;
       position: relative;
   }
   .image {
       width: 250px;
       padding: 80px;
   }
   .name {
       width: 200px;
       text-align: center;
   }
   .price {
       float: left;
       text-align: center;
       width: 100px;
   }
```

I want to display the products that I read from database in a side-by-side manner, just like in shopping websites. I want three products in a row. How could I do it?

Comment: I'm not able to display my contents side by side.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to wrap every product in a container. E.g.

```
<div id="productgrid">
    <div class="product" style="float: left; width: 200px;">
        Image and description goes here.
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem is** that you have set `container` => `width: 200px;` and every element in it is also `200px`+, so they will always align in new align as all the child divs are taking full width of container.

Also, you have floated the container but not the childs,so everytime a div is created, it will take the left most position.

**solution**

- increase width of the `container` div, and
- add `float: left;` to all the childs

<kbd>[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LL3nV/1/)</kbd>

**EDIT**

You will need to remove fixed width from child `div`s and wrap all the products in a single class and then float them

```
.product {
    float:left
}
```

[**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LL3nV/2/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But that's not how I want. The name should appear below image and the price below that. The image,name,price together constitute a single product. I want those products to be displayed side-by-side not its individual values.

Comment: gotcha...updating fiddle...give me a minute!! :)

Comment: @user2691793 : added the **edit** ,if you don't have to support old browsers then i would suggest you to look into `display:table` mehod, its much cleaner!!